# Python-SciPy Voronoi diagram accuracy

Tags: python, scipy, voronoi, scipy-spatial, qhull

I was using SciPy-Voronoi diagrams to generate some figures, and my professor and I observed something interesting. The line connecting any two sites (input points) should be a perpendicular bisector from the mathematical definition. However, in the following figure, you will see that it is not the case. I have generated 15 random points along with the border points of [0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1] to mitigate errors created by the infinite boundaries.
[image]

I know that Scipy-Voronoi uses Qhull in the background, so if anyone knows about that, I would be happy to hear their opinion as well.

My academic background is not mathematical, so if anyone let me know if this is an error in Scipy-Voronoi or my understanding, I would appreciate it.

Pranav

Comment: I think this may be an optical illusion since you are not using equal aspect ratio; try running `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt; plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10, 10)` before the plot.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem I tried it on several cases and it seems that it solved the problem. Thank you. I think Voronoi plotting function should include this by default.